# Unbalanced Parenthesis (Batch file)

Tags: batch-file, set, delimiter, parentheses

I am having the following error in my minimum working example. I have not had this problem until recently. But, I am having this problem on both my laptop (Windows 8.1) and my desktop (Windows 10). Any help would be appreciated.

Batch file contents:

```
@echo off
SET STARTTIME=%TIME%
set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)
```

Output: `Unbalanced parenthesis.`

Answer (score 5):

```
SET STARTTIME=%TIME%
SET "starttime=%starttime: =0%"
```

Unfortunately, you didn't show us what your `%time%` shows. It varies with installation.

In all probability, your time when time is earlier than 10:00 starts with a space.

The above line substitues `0` for <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: +1, Yes, SET /A fails at the very beginning when the space results in something like `set /a starttime=(1 7*360000...`. SET /A encounters `(N N...` and expects either an operator or close paren before the 2nd number. i'm a little surprised at the error message - I would have expected "Missing operator" instead.. A simpler solution is to modify the initial SET instead of adding another one: `set "STARTTIME=%TIME: =0%"`.

Comment: You're right. I messed up in not telling you at what %TIME% returned. I think I ran that command immediately after midnight (00:XX:YY.ZZ). I will check to make sure I can replicate this behavior tomorrow morning (it's already after 10A where I am). @Magoo, you gave me a solution and the reasoning, but I'll default to using dbenham's solution since it's more elegant, in practice. Thanks for your time, both.